# How to get output of exe in python script?

Tags: python, ide, executable, redirect

When I call an external `.exe` program in Python, how can I get `printf` output from the `.exe` application and print it to my Python IDE?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To call an external program from Python, use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module.

> The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.

An example from the doc (`output` is a file object that provides output from the child process.):

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

A concrete example, using `cmd`, the Windows command line interpreter with 2 arguments:

```
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(["cmd", "/C", "date"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p1.communicate()[0]
'The current date is: Tue 04/14/2009 \r\nEnter the new date: (mm-dd-yy) '
>>>
```

Comment: No, don't use os.popen(), it's been obsoleted by subprocess.

Comment: then how can I set the enviorment variables in this condition?myarg is the env var?

Comment: No, 'myarg' is argument to the command 'mycmd'.  You can pass an environment using the 'env' keyword argument.  Give it a dictionary containing the environment you want to use.

Comment: use subprocess.Popen([.....], stdout=..., env="YOUR ENV DICTIONARY")
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231227/python-subprocess-popen-with-a-modified-environment

Comment: In Python 3 you may want to use `...communicate()[0].decode()` to get the the actual `string` output, and not the `byte` output.

Comment: i have a compile c application which I am running on linux environment. It is a huge code fetching data from sensors in while loop. Does the example stated above  be able to fetch the data from that c application as well or "Only" those applications which gets terminated (returnd from main - return 0 or some exit code)

Answer (score 7):

I am pretty sure that you are talking about Windows here (based on the phrasing of your question), but in a Unix/Linux (including Mac) environment, the commands module is also available:

```
import commands

( stat, output ) = commands.getstatusoutput( "somecommand" )

if( stat == 0 ):
    print "Command succeeded, here is the output: %s" % output
else:
    print "Command failed, here is the output: %s" % output
```

The commands module provides an extremely simple interface to run commands and get the status (return code) and the output (reads from stdout and stderr). Optionally, you can get just status or just output by calling commands.getstatus() or commands.getoutput() respectively.

Comment: The answer above applies to python2, in python3 getstatusoutput and getoutput can be found in subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `subprocess.check_output(['mycmd', 'myargs'])`

Example:

```py
import subprocess

print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-1']).decode())
```