# How to retrieve, the return value from exe by executing the python script

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, exe

I have a python script for concatenate strings. You can find the code below. I have converted this .py file to exe.

[Concat.exe - Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g4Fr.png)

```
import sys

def concat_name(firstname, secondname):
    fullname = firstname + ' ' + secondname
    return fullname


fullname = (concat_name(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

When I am executing the .exe file in the command prompt, getting the expected result.

```
>concat.exe Juan Carlos
Juan Carlos
```

[Concat.exe - execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ2L7.png)
Now I have another Python script generate_name.py, and this script calling the concate.exe with relevant params. Please find the below code,

```
import sys
import subprocess

full_name = subprocess.check_output(['concat.exe', 'Juan' , 'Carlos'])
print(full_name)
```

[generate_name.py - code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nTrG.png)

But here I can not retrieve and print the output from the concat.exe. 
So can anyone help out on this issue?

Thanks in Advance,
Raj

Comment: Please post the error message you're getting

Comment: It's successfully executing no error message.

Comment: It may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748028/how-to-get-output-of-exe-in-python-script