# How to get return value of cpp function in Python using its executable?

Tags: python, c++

I am trying to build an executable using C++ and design a function having multi-dim tensor array value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <torch/script.h>

int main() {
    torch::Tensor tensor = torch::rand({1, 400, 400});
    /* print out or return 'tensor' value somehow*/
    return 0
}
```

And I would like to get the `tensor` value from Python side using the executable file.

Although there are some posts about retrieving stdout of executable in Python using subprocess (such as this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748028/how-to-get-output-of-exe-in-python-script)),
I don't see approaches on how to get the numerically equal variable value of cpp function in Python using executable.

Even if I try to `std::cout` tensor value in cpp, the printed value is cutoff as below. So, it is not numerically equal with the original value in cpp.

```
  ...
  2.5478e-01  2.9543e-01  9.1405e-01  7.1981e-01
  6.6557e-01  1.6238e-01  3.8278e-01  4.9424e-01
  5.1383e-01  1.6593e-01  8.5924e-01  3.8744e-01
  9.9829e-01  4.2506e-02  1.2164e-01  8.0078e-03
  4.3933e-02  9.7834e-01  9.4632e-01  5.5783e-01
  6.2664e-01  6.1711e-02  1.9250e-01  9.3781e-01
  8.9360e-01  8.6810e-01  2.5314e-01  8.9651e-01
  1.2310e-01  6.8445e-02  8.3720e-01  5.6933e-01
[ CPUFloatType{1,400,400} ]
```

Can I get any advices on this issue?
Thank you very much.

Comment: `main` can only return `int`, you need to print out your result instead

Comment: You can return any value from an executable, this is the return value from main.
Then from python you can get that code as described here : https://csatlas.com/python-subprocess-run-exit-code/

Comment: You'll need to modify the cpp program's printing routine to print the exact values rather than rounded-off approximations -- you could do that by calling the appropriate iostream methods, or if you don't like the C++ iostream API, you could replace the `cout`-based printing routine with one that uses `printf()` or similar instead.  Once you have it printing out values that you can use, then it's just a matter of updating your Python program to parse those values.

Comment: You could also consider compiling your functions into a shared library and then loading it in python using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). Another option could be to use [PyBind](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html) to expose some bindings for your functions written in C/C++.